# MFC resource-script file: Control description replaced by Control ID

Tags: mfc, resource-file

I am maintaining an MFC project, there is something strange about the **.rc** file. I inserted an menu in Resource View and I added two items in this menu.

Visual Studio assigns two IDs to these two items. Assume that the ID is 1000 and 1001. In **resource.h**,we can find `#define ID_MENU1_SUB1 1000` and `#define ID_MENU2_SUB2 1001`, this is okay. But in **.rc** file:

```
IDR_MENU MENU

BEGIN    
    POPUP "MENU1"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "Sub1",                        ID_MENU1_SUB1
        MENUITEM "Sub2",                        1001
    END
END
```

Why is `ID_MENU1_SUB2` automatically replaced by `1001`, even if the compilation has no problems. How can we avoid this.

Comment: I also saw this Problem from time to time in older VS-Versions. Seamed to be a bug. What VS Version are you using?

Comment: Thank you. I saw the change history, I think the version may be 2010 or 2012. Because every year we update the VS, I am afraid that I can't confirm accurate version about vs.

Comment: And I also can't find any topic about this in msdn.